# Disable Imagebutton on button click in asp.net using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to disable/enable dynamically created ImageButton in asp.net using Javascript or Jquery?
I am creating a imagebutton and i want to disable it on button click.
If anybody understand then please answer my question.
Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bellow code for that

- .aspx

  `<asp:ImageButton id="imgButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/img1.jpg" />`
  `<asp:Button id="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Click"/>`
- JavaScript

  `

  ```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#<%= btnClick.ClientID %>').click(function () {
          $('#<%= imgButton.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // Image Button Id which you want to disable.
      });
  });
  ```

  `

Comment: @Manish Jain Please click upvote or click 'correct' if above answer is useful.